# Bash script to delete files from remote FTP older than 7 days

Tags: bash, ftp, backup

i got a bash script from internet, its look good.
its already backup, upload FTP, delete old backups older than 7 days.

but its not delete old backup older than 7 days in remote FTP

```
#!/bin/sh
Mdate="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"
mysqldump -uroot -pPassword asia stats | gzip > /home/backup/asia_$Mdate.$

cd /home/backup/

ftpserver="ftp.drivehq.com"
ftpuser="username"
ftppass="password"

ftp -n -i $ftpserver <<EOF
user $ftpuser $ftppass
cd backupstats
mput asia_$Mdate.gz
quit
EOF

find /home/backup/asia_*.gz -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +7 -delete
```

the example backup name will like "asia_17-08-2014.gz"

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is asia_17-08-2014.gz the actual backup file name that not getting deleted?

Comment: no, thats just example backup name will created.

Comment: `find ... delete` is being run locally. And I don't see how a file you just created would be older than 7 days?

Comment: @BroSlow ya its delete local, thats why i ask script for delete remote ftp.
i run cronjob every day, so i have more than 20 old backups

Comment: Generally the easiest way to keep files for just 7 days is just to name them `.mon`, `.tue`, etc. Then you just overwrite the previous week's file every Monday, Tuesday, etc.

Comment: @pgl thanks, if i use mput command its replace old backup, or must add an option command?

Comment: @anonprophet Just overwrite the existing file. `mput` will do that, although that's actually for `m`ultiple puts, just `put` on its own will work.

If I add this as an answer, will you accept it?

Comment: @pgl ya, i will , u help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the easiest way to keep files for just 7 days is just to name them .mon, .tue, etc. Then you just overwrite the previous week's file every Monday, Tuesday, etc.